# how to find the minimal cover for a set of functional dependencies?

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I want to find the minimal cover for the following set of functional dependencies:

```
A -> BC

B -> C

A -> B

AB -> C
```

**first step: Break down the RHS of each functional dependency into a single attribute:**

```
A -> B

A -> C

B -> C

A -> B

AB -> C
```

then I will remove of the two **`A -> B`**, so we will get:

```
A -> B

A -> C

B -> C

AB -> C
```

**second step: Trying to remove unnecessary attributes from the LHS of each functional dependency (whose LHS has 2 or more attributes):**

for `AB -> C` , check if A is necessary by:

replace `AB -> C` with `B -> C` so if B+ contains C then A is unnecessary:

```
B+ = B (B -> C)

   = BC (so A is unnecessary)
```

check if B is necessary by:

replace `AB -> C` with `A -> C` so if A+ contains C then B is unnecessary:

```
A+ = A (A -> B)

   = AB (A -> C)

   = ABC (so B is unnecessary)
```

now we have:

```
A -> B

A -> C

B -> C
```

**third step: Trying to remove unecessary functional dependencies:**

for `A -> B` check if A+ contains B without using `A -> B`:

```
A+ = A (A -> C)

   = AC (so A -> B is necessary)
```

for `A -> C` check if A+ contains C without using `A -> C`:

```
A+ = A (A -> B)

   = AB (so A -> C is necessary)
```

for `B -> C` check if B+ contains C without using `B -> C`:

```
B+ = B (so B -> C is necessary)
```

now we have:

```
A -> B

A -> C

B -> C
```

Finally, group the functional dependencies that have common LHS together:

```
A -> BC

B -> C
```

so we can say that these functional dependencies are the minimal cover of the set, is that true ? and how we can deduce the key(s) of the set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute a canonical cover for F:

Use the union rule to replace any dependencies with common left-side.

so Combine A ->BC and A -> B into A -> BC
Set is now {A -> BC, B -> C, AB -> C}

A is extraneous in AB -> C

Check if the result of deleting A from  AB -> C  is implied by the other dependencies

Yes: in fact,  B -> C is already present!

Set is now {A -> BC, B -> C}

C is extraneous in A -> BC

Check if A -> C is logically implied by A  B and the other dependencies

Yes: using transitivity on A -> B  and B -> C.

Can use attribute closure of A in more complex cases

The canonical cover is:     A ->B, B -> C

source:Korth,sudarshan DBMS book.